# how to select records from table A and update table A

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM pgp 
WHERE group_id IN (
    SELECT group_id FROM pgroups 
    WHERE label LIKE 'Registration%' 
        AND label NOT LIKE '%Snom%'
) 
    AND pid = 12;
```

it returns results like:

```
 group_id | pid      | value | updatev
----------+----------+-------+----------
       34 |       12 |       | f
       11 |       12 |       | t
        4 |       12 |       | t
       13 |       12 |       | t
       17 |       12 |       | f
       19 |       12 |       | f
```

For all the records returned, I want to force the value of the "updatev" field to be set to true. I'm not sure how to do that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `SELECT` to an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE pgp
SET  updatev = 't'
WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM pgroups WHERE label like 'Registration%' and label not like '%Snom%') and pid = 12;
```

That's actually a good practice - get your criteria right with a `SELECT` before actually changing any data.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`update`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html) statement:

```
UPDATE pgp 
SET    updatev = true
WHERE  group_id IN (SELECT group_id 
                    FROM   pgroups 
                    WHERE  label LIKE 'Registration%' AND 
                           label NOT LIKE '%Snom%') AND
       pid = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

Might work

```
Update pgp 
set updatev='t'
WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM pgroups WHERE label like 'Registration%' and label not like '%Snom%') and pid = 12;
```